# Adding CTC Loss and CTC decode to a Keras model

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, handwriting-recognition, ctc

I am trying to solve a use case of handwritten text recognition. I have used CNN and LSTM to create a network. The output of this needs to be fed to a CTC layer. I could find some codes to do this in native tensorflow. Is there an easier option for this in Keras.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5,5),activation = 'relu', input_shape=(128,32,1), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(5,5),activation = 'relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(5,5),activation = 'relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(5,5),activation = 'relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(5,5),activation = 'relu', padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(5,5),activation = 'relu', padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,2),padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(5,5),activation = 'relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, 0, :], output_shape=(None,31,512), mask=None, arguments=None))
#model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(31, 256)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(75, activation = 'softmax'))
```

[image: Network Architecture before CTC loss and decode]

Any help on how we can easily add CTC Loss and Decode layers to this would be great

Answer (score 2):

A CTC loss function requires four arguments to compute the loss, predicted outputs, ground truth labels, input sequence length to LSTM and ground truth label length. To get this we need to create a custom loss function and then pass it to the model. To make it compatible with your defined model, we need to create a model which takes these four inputs and outputs the loss. This model will be used for training and for testing, the model that you have created earlier can be used.

Let's create a keras model that you used in a different way so that we can create  two different versions of the model to be used at training and testing time.

```
# input with shape of height=32 and width=128 
inputs = Input(shape=(32, 128, 1))

# convolution layer with kernel size (3,3)
conv_1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
# poolig layer with kernel size (2,2)
pool_1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2)(conv_1)

conv_2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_1)
pool_2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2)(conv_2)

conv_3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_2)

conv_4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_3)
# poolig layer with kernel size (2,1)
pool_4 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 1))(conv_4)

conv_5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_4)
# Batch normalization layer
batch_norm_5 = BatchNormalization()(conv_5)

conv_6 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(batch_norm_5)
batch_norm_6 = BatchNormalization()(conv_6)
pool_6 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 1))(batch_norm_6)

conv_7 = Conv2D(512, (2, 2), activation='relu')(pool_6)

squeezed = Lambda(lambda x: K.squeeze(x, 1))(conv_7)

# bidirectional LSTM layers with units=128
blstm_1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2))(squeezed)
blstm_2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2))(blstm_1)

outputs = Dense(len(char_list) + 1, activation='softmax')(blstm_2)

# model to be used at test time
test_model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

We will use ctc_loss_fuction during training. So, lets implement the ctc_loss_function and create a training model using ctc_loss_function:

```
labels = Input(name='the_labels', shape=[max_label_len], dtype='float32')
input_length = Input(name='input_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
label_length = Input(name='label_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')


def ctc_lambda_func(args):
    y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length = args

    return K.ctc_batch_cost(labels, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
  

loss_out = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name='ctc')([outputs, labels, 
input_length, label_length])

#model to be used at training time
training_model = Model(inputs=[inputs, labels, input_length, label_length], outputs=loss_out)
```

--> Train this model and save the weights in .h5 file

Now use the test model and load saved weights of the training model by using arguments by_name=True so it will load weights for only matching layers.